# Sum if Same Color Cell

Tags: vba, excel

How can I modify this code so that instead of just summing the same colored cells as `rColor`, it would sum based on `rColor` and the text in the cell?

For example, sum all yellow colored cells that contains the text "Nokia".

```
    Function ColorFunction(rColor As Range, rRange As Range, Optional SUM As Boolean)
        Dim rCell As Range
        Dim lCol As Long
        Dim vResult

        lCol = rColor.Interior.ColorIndex
        If SUM = True Then
            For Each rCell In rRange
                If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then
                    vResult = WorksheetFunction.SUM(rCell, vResult)
                End If
            Next rCell
        Else
            For Each rCell In rRange
                If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then
                    vResult = 1 + vResult
                End If
            Next rCell
        End If

        ColorFunction = vResult
    End Function
```

i have this table and i want the red cell to return 2000 instead of 3000 so rather than summing the 3 yellow cells i want it to sum the two yellow colored nokia cells.

[image: colorFunction]

Comment: set a break point on lcol and look at the value as you stop through the function. (F8)  when you see how the system records yellow note it and instead if the if statemetn checking against lcol, check against how it records yellow. next on the if statements check the rcell.text for "Nokia"

Comment: sorry i cant exaclty follow what your saying, could you please make this clearer, thank you ^^

Comment: added an answer to show a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Function ColorFunction(rColor As Range, rRange As Range, Optional SUM As Boolean, Optional valToSumOn As String)
        Dim rCell As Range
        Dim lCol As Long
        Dim vResult

        lCol = rColor.Interior.ColorIndex '6 is yellow
        If SUM = True Then
            For Each rCell In rRange
                If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol And (Cells(rCell.Row, rCell.Column - 1).Text = valToSumOn Or valToSumOn = "") Then
                    vResult = WorksheetFunction.SUM(rCell, vResult)
                End If
            Next rCell
        Else
            For Each rCell In rRange
                If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol And (Cells(rCell.Row, rCell.Column - 1).Text = valToSumOn Or valToSumOn = "") Then
                    vResult = 1 + vResult
                End If
            Next rCell
        End If

        ColorFunction = vResult
    End Function
```

Since I modified the function to include an optional parameter for the text... the formula for the sum cell is now `=colorfunction(E4,F4:F10,TRUE,"Nokia")`

I added an optional parameter to define the text to look for in column before the sum column.
I then check to see if this value is set. If it matches the quantity we are about to sum, it adds it to the some otherwise it skips it.   However if no text is set, it simply sums all matching colors.

[image]

Comment: We could handle the text like that of the color were you simply Specify the cell containing the desired text to sum on. lots of options here.

Comment: Thank you very much this worked beautifly, i used `rCell.Offset(0, -1).text = iText` where `iText = rColor.text` so i dont have to define the text manually just using the E4.